# Error por archivo no encontrado trás lanzar ejecutable creado con cx_freeze

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy tratando de generar un .exe con *cx_freeze*.

El problema es que al terminar el proceso build y generar el .exe lanza el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El programa consta de 2 archivos un script y una interfaz en pyqt5

> 1.- Calculadora.py
>   2.- calculadora.ui

y este es el script `setup.py` que ejecute para generar el .exe en *cx_freeze*:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(

    name = "Calculadora",
    version = "1.0.0",
    description = "A calculcator system",
    executables = [Executable("Calc.py",base="Win32GUI")]

)
```

¿Pueden decirme que faltó?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según el error no se encuentra el archivo `.ui`. ***cx_Freeze*** no es capaz de detectar e incluir de forma automática los archivos que abras con `open`, `uic.loadUi` como en este caso, etc. Debes especificar los archivos/directorios que se deben incluir de forma explícita en el `setup.py`. Esto se hace mediante la opción [`include_files`](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/distutils.html#build-exe), lo que permitirá a cx_Freeze buscar y copiar el archivo.

> **Aviso:** Tu .ui según el error se llama ***nuevo.ui*** y tu ejecutable ***Calc.py*** según tu setup.py. Voy a usar ***calculadora.py*** y ***calculadora.ui*** como dices tener, suponiendo que ambos están en el mismo directorio y que lanzas el setup.py desde el mismo. **En caso contrario debes modificar las rutas**.

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable



includefiles = ["calculadora.ui"]  # Agrega aquí las rutas de tus archivos.
includes = []
excludes = ['tkinter']
packages = []

setup(
    name = "Calculadora",
    version = '1.0.0',
    description = "A calculcator system",
    options = {'build_exe': {'includes': includes,
                             'excludes': excludes,
                             'packages': packages,
                             'include_files': includefiles}},

    executables = [Executable('calculadora.py', base="Win32GUI")]
)
```

Con esto el ejecutable debe crearse sin problemas. En realidad simplemente se limita a copiar el archivo en el directorio *build*, al mismo nivel que el exe.  Te recomiendo usar rutas relativas siempre en tu app para facilitar la portabilidad cuando uses recursos ligados a la propia app como es el .ui. Si tus archivos están en subdirectorios debes añadir dichos directorios en el a `include_files`,  por ejemplo, si tu `calculadora.ui` estuviera en `source/designer` deberías hacer:

```
includefiles = ["source/designer"]
```

y en el código lo cargarías usando la ruta relativa con:

```
uic.loadUi('source/designer/calculadora.ui', self)
```

Answer (score 0):

No queda del todo claro si el error te aparece mientras generas el .exe, que es lo que dices en la pregunta, o más bien cuando intentas ejecutar el .exe resultante, que es lo que se deduce de la captura de pantalla que adjuntas. Voy a suponer que es el segundo caso.

Si lees la última línea de la alerta de error que te saltó (siempre hay que leer eso), verás que dice:

> FileNotFound error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'nuevo.ui'

Es decir, el programa al ejecutarse intenta leer un archivo llamado `nuevo.ui` y no lo encuentra. No mencionas ese archivo en tu pregunta, sino otro llamado `calculadora.ui`. Quizás es un error de transcripción tuyo, o quizás es otro fichero.

En cualquier caso, estamos ante el caso de un programa python que necesita acceder a recursos (ficheros) externos. Como se explica en [el manual de cx_freeze](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#using-data-files), esos ficheros no son añadidos automáticamente al .exe construido por `cx_freeze`, sino que tienes que indicarle que lo haga, añadiendo al `setup.py` algo como esto:

```
ficheros_extra = ['calculadora.ui', 'nuevo.ui']
setup(
    name = "Calculadora",
    version = "1.0.0",
    description = "A calculcator system",
    executables = [Executable("Calc.py",base="Win32GUI")],
    options = {'build_exe': {'include_files': ficheros_extra}}
)
```

Eso incluiría los ficheros listados en `ficheros_extra` (las rutas a esos ficheros han de ser relativas a `Calculadora.py`) en la carpeta `build` que acompaña al ejecutable.

No obstante ahí no acaba la cosa. Desde la aplicación python, cuando vayas a cargar uno de esos archivos, deberás indicar la ruta absoluta de dónde están, y esa ruta depende de si la aplicación está "congelada" (en cuyo caso el archivo estará en la carpeta `build` donde se haya instalado el ejecutable) o no (en cuyo caso estará en la carpeta donde esté el `.py`).

El siguiente código tomado de la documentación te resuelve esto:

```
def find_data_file(filename):
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        # The application is frozen
        datadir = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
    else:
        # The application is not frozen
        # Change this bit to match where you store your data files:
        datadir = os.path.dirname(__file__)

    return os.path.join(datadir, filename)
```

La documentación hace referencia también a [un tutorial sobre recursos PyQt](http://lateral.netmanagers.com.ar/stories/BBS49.html) que ha desaparecido ya de internet, pero que aún puede consultarse en la copia que el día [25 de agosto de 2013 hizo el Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20130825084957/http://lateral.netmanagers.com.ar/stories/BBS49.html).